# Custom layout z-index

Tags: html, css, layout

I need help with this custom layout. Can someone tell me how to create css code for those 3 div's and get this results ?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Kaskader, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you include any html and css you already have in an attempt to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I dont have any html code. I'm just wondering how it can be done.

Comment: @Kaskader207 SO is **NOT** a code writing service. Please come back when you have a specific qustion

Comment: @Kaskader207 for future posts on SO, make sure you have tried to replicate whatever you are posting about, make sure you explain the methods you have tried to use, include the code you use so others can pinpoint problems, and have a definite question. This will make sure you get quality answers quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you don't have any code to start with, here is a beginning spot. Note that a lot of these have vendor prefixes and may of these have shorthand ways of writing them (padding, margin etc..). I just wrote everything out for visual purposes.

```css
div{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
}

.black{
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

h1.black{
  color:white;
}

.white{
  position:relative;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

div.overlay{
  margin-top:140px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  float: center;
  border: 3px solid silver;
  background: linear-gradient(silver,#A9A9A9);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="black">
    <h1 class="black">Div 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="white">
    <h1> Div 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1>Div 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

as a starting point:

the three div should be contained in the same container,
the container takes 100% of the availible height and is positioned relative. 
each background div take 50% of the height and are also positioned relative.

using the `.v-centered` CSS class we can center elements vertically and horizontally inside of relative containers using : `top:50% and transform: translateY(-50%)` and horizontally `margin: 0 auto`.

the foreground has a higher z-index then other `.v-centered` content to appear on top

the issue you can see is that the content of the background divs is centered inside the divs and does not take into account the height of the foreground div, this is because it is positionned in absolute, if your central div has always the same height, you could add padding to the content of the background to adress that issue.

```css
html, 
body {
  height:100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.container {
  text-align:center;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.color--dark {
  background: black;
  color:white;
}

.color--light {
  background: white;
}

.background {
  position:relative;
  height :50%;
}

.v-centered {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.foreground {
  width:60%;
  background:grey;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="background color--dark"> 
    <span class="v-centered"> DIV 1 </span>    
  </div>
  
  <div class="foreground v-centered"> DIV 2 </div>
  
  <div class="background color--light">   
    <span class="v-centered"> DIV 3 </span>    
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that can work.

The trick is to set the middle div `.button.-absolute` to absolute positioning and make sure its placed within the upper black div `.top-black`. This element needs `position: absolute` for this to work. Because of its absolute positioning use bottom and left to align it on the fold of the two colours meeting. No z-index is needed yet, but if you see other items overlapping them, add a higher value e.g. `z-index: 10` to the element that needs to be on top. The gradient background can be achieved by using `background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #cccccc 100%);`

I hope this helps and here's it in action.

```css
body {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.top-black {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 100% min-height: 225px;
  content: ' ';
}

.bottom-white {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100% min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.button {
  padding: 3rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button.-absolute {
  padding: 1rem 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2rem;
  left: calc(50% - 7.5rem);
  background-color: red;
}

.button.-filled {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #cccccc 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#cccccc', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}

.button.-white {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-black">
  <div class="button -white">DIV I</div>
  <div class="button -absolute -filled">DIV I</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-white">
  <div class="button">DIV I</div>
</div>
```